# bash assign variable to array elements

Tags: bash, shell

I'm having a trouble getting this working in bash, I have the following array

```
server-farm=("10.0.10.1" 10.0.10.2")
```

I would like to loop through this array and assign uniq variable to each element.

Desired results.

```
srv1 = 10.0.10.1 
srv2 = 10.0.10.2
```

Is this possible?

This is what I have tried so far, but couldn't get it to work.

```
  for i in "${server_farm[@]}"
    do
            echo $i
  done
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to assign each value to a different variable? There's no need to do that. Use the array directly. `${server_farm[0]}` is the first entry, `${server_farm[1]}` is the second, etc.

Comment: `bash` variables can't have hyphens in their names. So your array assignment is a bit suspect to begin with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script:

```
server_farm=("10.0.10.1" "10.0.10.2")

for ((i=0, j=1; i< ${#server_farm[@]}; i++, j++)); do
   declare "srv$j"="${server_farm[$i]}"
done
```

Test:

```
echo "$srv1"
10.0.10.1
echo "$srv2"
10.0.10.2
```

Comment: Thanks very much, what is the meaning of the # before server_farm? Just curious to know, thanks

Comment: `${#server_farm[@]}` gives us count of array elements